# Size list after its tallest element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list with *n* list elements. The height of the element is determined by its contents. Only one element is shown at a time; the rest are hidden with CSS (display: none).

I'd like the UL element to retain its height when the tallest of the elements is hidden. Any ideas what I can do to achieve this?

Example:

UL height 200px:

```
<ul>
   <li>Nulla sed egestas ante. Integer aliquet lectus ac felis euismod ultrices. Praesent magna libero, vestibulum nec tincidunt ac, lacinia et nibh. Pellentesque laoreet, turpis sed consectetur ullamcorper, dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
   <li style="display:none">dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
   <li style="display:none">Aliquet lectus dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
</ul>
```

UL height 100px:

```
<ul>
   <li style="display:none">Nulla sed egestas ante. Integer aliquet lectus ac felis euismod ultrices. Praesent magna libero, vestibulum nec tincidunt ac, lacinia et nibh. Pellentesque laoreet, turpis sed consectetur ullamcorper, dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
   <li>dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
   <li style="display:none">Aliquet lectus dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
</ul>
```

I'd love to see a CSS solution to this problem!

**Edit**

As some of you might've realised already, the list is used as a slideshow. I'm using jQuery hide/show to switch between the elements. Unfortunately, the list "jumps" with every transition, especially between two elements of mismatching height.

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Edit 2**

I've come up with a scripty solution to the problem. I'm not entirely satisfied with it.

```js
var i = 0; 

window.setInterval(function () {
  $('ul').css({marginLeft: -300 * i});
  i += 1;
  if ( i > $('ul li').length) {
    i = 0;
    }
  }, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  }

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 900px;  
  margin-left: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul>
       <li>Nulla sed egestas ante. Integer aliquet lectus ac felis euismod ultrices. Praesent magna libero, vestibulum nec tincidunt ac, lacinia et nibh. Pellentesque laoreet, turpis sed consectetur ullamcorper, dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
       <li>dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
       <li>Aliquet lectus dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you using any css for this? If so post that too.. or create a demo what you tried sofar?

Comment: @Etash I've updaded my question!

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but can't you just apply a fixed height of 200px to your containing div?

Comment: @Ursus The elements' height is determined by their content... which is, in this case, textual. I'd like the height of all the elements to flow naturally with the tallest element in the list. We decided in the end to implement my solution above, albeit with percentages instead of pixels. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We decided to work with my own solution, but with percentages instead. The only bit of JavaScript you'd need then is the bit which assigns the left margin, and the width in percentages (100 / *n*) of the list elements.

Answer (score 0):

Browser cant know the height of your max height item if he's hidden at the start, you should used an js script here to detect and retain the more biggest item here like:

```js
$(function(){
  var hUl = 0;
  $('li').each( function(k, li){
    var isVisible = $(li).is(':visible');
    if(!isVisible) {$(li).show();}
    hUl =($(li).height() > hUl) ? $(li).height() : hUl;
    $('ul').height(hUl);
    if(!isVisible) {$(li).hide();}
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
   <li style="display:none;">Nulla sed egestas ante. Integer aliquet lectus ac felis euismod ultrices. Praesent magna libero, vestibulum nec tincidunt ac, lacinia et nibh. Pellentesque laoreet, turpis sed consectetur ullamcorper, dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
   <li>dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
   <li style="display:none;">Aliquet lectus dolor turpis mollis nulla, at finibus nibh magna vitae velit.</li>
</ul>
```